# Python: Case for `dependency injection`?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, module

At the moment I am refactoring a program I wrote a while ago. There are a bunch of classes, so their decoupling is easy. I tried to group most of the functions as well, put them in a class and make `staticmethod`'s out of them.

Often they use an instance of one the objects. Now they all have their own namespace and I need to pass the instance explicitly into the function, sometimes even across multiple modules. My question really is: is this a classic case for `dependency injection`?

What would be an alternative way to make some variables `global` in the scope of the package?

Comment: I think so.. But why isn't DI clean?

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to say so. I meant another clean way, if that makes any sense.